# How to cancel a JCL job(Mainframe) in SDSF???(OZA1) error

Tags: mainframe, jcl, mvs, ispf, tso

I received a JCL Error after submitting a job.

> 20.46.44 JOB08763 $HASP165 WPR062M  ENDED AT OZA1 - JCL ERROR CN(INTERNAL).

and in SDSF I am seeing this

[image]

How can I fix this (Cancel the job)? What is the reason for this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error? You'll need to post the output from your WPR062M job showing the JCL error for us to help fix it. Cschneid has already explained that your screen shot is not showing your failed job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are authorized to do so, you can cancel a job in SDSF by putting a C in the "N P" column and pressing the Enter key.  But, that's your TSO session (the JobID starts with TSU) and you probably don't want to cancel it.  The message you received indicated the job you submitted had a JCL error and ended, so there's no need to cancel it because it's no longer running.

Comment: Ah yes - when you accidentally cancel your TSO session rather than the job that's above it in SDSF's DA screen...

Answer (score 0):

The job shown in the screen shot is your current TSO session; you don't want to cancel this, do you? (BTW, please post text instead of images whenever possible).

The jobname of the one in the screen shot is `WPR062` and the jobid is `TSU08747`. The `TSU` prefix in the jobid tells you its a TSO session.

The job (not TSO session) in error which gave you this message:

```
20.46.44 JOB08763 $HASP165 WPR062M ENDED AT OZA1 - JCL ERROR CN(INTERNAL)
```

has a jobname `WPR026M` with jobid `JOB08763`. The `JOB` prefix tells you its a batch job.

You need to look at the job's output in SDSD to find out what caused the JCL error.

For completeness:

- Started task have a jobid prefix of `STC`.
- If your system is configured to allow more than 99'999 active jobids, the prefixes will become single character, i.e. `T` for TSO sessions, `J` for batch jobs, and `S` for started tasks.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated the SDSF output you are looking at is showing your TSO UserID.  That is long running and is not the job that is in error.

According to the error message

> 20.46.44 JOB08763 $HASP165 WPR062M ENDED AT OZA1 - JCL ERROR CN(INTERNAL)

The actual jobname is `WPR062M`.  To investigate the issue I suggest that you use the command `PREFIX WMPR062*` and then use the `H` command.  The output you are looking for is in the **H**eld queue.

Investigate that job by putting an `S` in the `Cmd`Line (note, I don't have `SDSF` on my system but the command column is located on the left side of the screen.

In that job will be the reason for the `JCL`error.